# Compile wix project using "Any CPU" instead of "X86"

Tags: compilation, wix

When I compile a wix project, and wix launch the compilation via MSbuild of all the existing projects, can I use "Any CPU" instead of "X86" or "64 bit" ?

If not, how can I compile the projects using "Any CPU" ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If your question is whether you can compile WIXPROJ for `Any CPU` then the answer is no.

> "WiX projects will not be built when building the 'Any CPU' platform
>   because **Windows Installer packages are CPU-specific.**"

The `TargetPlatform` setting in your WIXPROJ defines the way Windows Installer treats folder variables, registries and GAC etc. For example, the setup project will use the `[ProgramFiles64Folder]` variable if the `TargetPlatform` of the setup project is x64; and `[ProgramFilesFolder]` for x86.

Check this answer, it will be helpful:
http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Any-CPU-platform-in-wix-3-0-td3441097.html

Answer (score 3):

**Step1:** Go to solution Properties
**Step2:** Configuration properties --> Configuration
**Step3:** Check the build option for WIX project.

Comment: +1 This answer is not (really) related to this question. This question was also not what I was looking for. BUT this answer was the correct answer to the question I was looking for. =) :D