# Wix installer project build skipped in Any CPU solution

Tags: visual-studio, build, wix, wix3.8

I'm trying to build a solution that is configured as Release | Any CPU that contains a Wix installer project which is configured for x86. Everything in the solution is built fine but Wix installer is always skipped.

It works fine building in visual studio but from the command line there are issues.

I'm calling it like so:

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)//Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/devenv.com" /Rebuild "Release|Any CPU" "MySolution.sln"
```

And this is the error

```
Skipped Rebuild All: Project: Service.WixInstall, Configuration: Release x86 ----- Project not selected to build for this solution configuration
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an error; It's just for your information.

> Project not selected to build for this solution configuration

Open the configuration manager, select the solution configuration and solution platform. Then in the row for the project, select the project configuration and the project platform that you want built with the solution.

[How to: Create and Edit Configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kwybya3w(v=vs.100).aspx)

IIRC, Visual Studio Express has reduced configuration functionality. If that's a problem for you, you can edit the solution file with a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the wix project build is selected with in the Configuration Manager -> Active Solution Platform -> "Any CPU".

Answer (score 0):

Check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21173022/132599). In particular:

> "WiX projects will not be built when building the 'Any CPU' platform
>   because **Windows Installer packages are CPU-specific.**"

The nabble link in the SO answer is a reference to [this wix-users mailing list entry](https://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg31334.html) and contains some useful links.